# Classifying infinite languages of encodings of halting Turing machines

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Given this question:

> $L$ is an infinite language of encoded Turing machines who always halt.
>
> 1. $L$ might be decidable
> 2. $L$ might be in RE but not in R
> 3. both 1. and 2. are correct

I know the solution to this question is 3., but I seem to lack the understanding on how am I suppose to get to that solution. Could you explain how should I approach this kind of questions? Am I supposed to start drawing TMs?
Why is the answer is C? What's the indication of that?

It would help me a lot if you could explain to me your thought process when facing this kind of problem.

Comment: Option *c* cannot be correct since *a* and *b* contradict each other: a language is decidable if and only if it is in $R$.

Comment: Thought process: which results do I know that yield (non)decidability and (non-)semi-decidability? Which do apply?

Comment: sorry, i left the 'might' in (a) out when translating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly examples for all "levels":

1. It is easy to give an infinite set of encodings that is decidable.

   > Consider all programs of the form `f(x) = x + i` -- definitely an infinite and decidable set.
2. Classic examples (think Halting problem) are semi-decidable but not decidable.

   > $L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid f_M(\langle M \rangle) = 1\}$
3. Other classic examples (think complement of Halting problem) are not semi-decidable.

   > $L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid f_M(\langle M \rangle)\uparrow \}$

Comment: what is FmTotal?

Comment: @AC9000 "$f_M$ total" means that the function the Turing machine computes is total, i.e. $M$ always halts.